# How to process Observable<Response>

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jersey, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have one local spring boot application which is hitting another PCF deployed application. The PCF application is giving me list of Student.

I am hitting the same using:

```
Observable<Response> result = RxObservable.newClient()
  .target(url)
  .request()
  .rx()
  .get();
```

Now I am not able to get my `List<Student>` back from result `Observable`.

Tried lots of approaches but nothing really working i.e. subscribing to result etc etc.

Comment: The documentation is too much extensive :)

Answer (score 1):

So after struggling for few hours below is the solution for now.

```
Observable observable =  result.map(response -> response.readEntity(List.class));
DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<Response>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult(Duration.ofMillis(10000L).toMillis());
    observable.subscribe((response) -> {
        ResponseEntity<Response> responseData = new ResonseEntity(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        deferredResult.setResult(responseData);
    },  deferredResult::setErrorResult);
```

Please suggest, if it can be improved.

Thanks